# Font library for XNA

Tags: xna, windows-phone-7, fonts

Is there a free type library kind of implementation available for XNA? I wish to use it on WP7, so it should be a managed code. I know can alternatively use spritefont, but I wish to know if other implementations exist for complex requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The nuclex library has more than one font renderer.

Developer's blog, [article discussing why XNA 4 fonts don't render as well as they could](http://www.nuclex.org/blog/2-gamedev/113-xna-sprite-font-quality) with spritebatch, with before and after comparisons of Nuclex font rendering vs Spritebatch in XNA4.

[Nuclex Fonts wiki](https://devel.nuclex.org/framework/wiki/NuclexFonts).

Nuclex [Vector fonts](https://github.com/remiomosowon/NuclexFramework/blob/master/nuclex-framework-r1404-sources/framework/Nuclex.Fonts/Source/VectorFont.cs) (very useful for large fonts or fonts that need to be drawn well in 3D).

XNA 4 uses DXT compression on it's font textures, which causes the edges of fonts to be a little uglier than they need to be. XNA also has no Vector font implementation, which Nuclex does.

The Nuclex font **source code** can be found here:
https://devel.nuclex.org/framework/svn/graphics/fonts/

Comment: @Vijayendra Please mark as answer if it fits your needs!